why does a new LED ceiling light in my utility room flicker when I have my under the cabinet lights on in the kitchen
I installed a new LED ceiling light in my utility room. when we turned the power on the light started flickering. We thought it was loose wires so we tightehed the cinnections and moved the ground wire to a screw in the box. The flickering stopped. We put the light back together and went upon our way. Later my wife turned the light on and it began to flicker. That night when i went to bed I turned on the light and it was not flickerirng. the next morning when I turned it on it flickered. I turned off my under the cabinet lighs in the kitchen and the flickering stopped.

Are they on the same circuit?
